# Is it possible to use implicit parameters when defining routing directives?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a directive, defined like

```
def allowedRoles(roles: UserRole*)(implicit login: Login): Directive0 = ???
```

But I don;t seem to be able to use it in without having to *explicitly* pass in the `login` parameter

```
def myRoutes(implicit req: HttpRequest, login: Login) = {
  path("example" / "path") {
    get {
      allowedRoles(Administrator) { // ← fails 
        handleGet
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if I try to compile this it fails with a type mismatch:

```
[error]  found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
[error]     (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
[error]  required: com.example.Login
[error]         allowedRoles(Administrator) { handleGet } }
```

if I change the marked line to `allowedRoles(Administrator)(login)` then it works, but it seems like I should not need to do this, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to define login (inside myRoutes definition) as implicit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because by Scala rules, `{ handleGet }` is considered the second parameter list of `allowedRoles`. To fix this, make it clear it's actually the parameter of `Directive0.apply`:

```
allowedRoles(Administrator).apply { handleGet }
```